# Zoomed out on ipad how to set normal view

Tags: ios, ipad

My ipad under ios14 has got to a stage where I have zoomed in.

How do,I reset the screen to.normal
The thumb and finger pinch seems to do nothing other pinches take me to.the tsk screen showing all safari tabs or all apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accessibility zoom feature can be turned on and off with a double three-finger tap.

To control the zoom level, double three-finger tap and hold the second tap, then move your fingers up and down the screen to zoom in and out respectively. Pan with three finger drag.